# What would be the best course of action for display different form in a single Winform?

Tags: c#, winforms

Here's a screenshot of my application:
[image]

Basically, depending on what option is selected I'd like to show another 'content' which can be a buttons, or forms or whatever.

What would be the best choice for this? Using MDI? I'm really new to this type of thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This scenario lends itself well to tab pages, as you'd find on a `TabControl`.

However, since you already have a mechanism for switching between the content, you might prefer to create a series of `Panel`s whose `Dock` property is set to `DockStyle.Fill`. When the user clicks the appropriate heading, you simply need to show the appropriate panel and call `BringToFront()` on it. This is essentially what the tab control does internally, anyway.

Don't forget to use `SuspendLayout()` and `ResumeLayout()` appropriately to reduce flicker, which can be a huge problem in WinForms applications, especially when there are lots of controls.

Comment: Brilliant! Sounds good on paper, let me hack something together and test it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can position a `TabControl` where the buttons are not visible and control it from your buttons.

Comment: What property is there to not display  the buttons, but only the square content?

Comment: @Sergio: Unfortunately, there's no such property. However, you can subclass the tab control and add one yourself without much work. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798215/hide-tabcontrol-buttons-to-manage-stacked-panel-controls/2798241#2798241) for a drop-in solution.