# Edit custom panel graphically in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have a custom TableLayout panel (but the same question is valid for buttons, panels, etc):

```
Public Class WellFLAddRow
    Inherits TableLayoutPanel

    [...]

End class
```

I want to add some controls and edit its properties by using the Designer environment. I tried to follow the answer to [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704548/editing-custom-controls-or-panels-in-the-designer-environment), but the proposed solution (set Dock=fill) doesn't work for me...

Is there a way to show and edit this custom TLPanel graphically?

Comment: Same comment from the other question...it sounds like you want a UserControl instead of an Inherited Control.  Start with a UserControl, then add the TableLayoutPanel to that.  This will allow you to visually design it as a unit.

Comment: I think [this](http://www.reza-aghaei.com/enable-designer-of-child-panel-in-a-usercontrol) might be useful for adding controls to a custom container control via the designer. Others than that the `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't support [Visual Inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/walkthrough-demonstrating-visual-inheritance).