# Hide Controls At Design-Time

Tags: visual-studio-2012

In my application i am adding a lot of controls all on top of each other (winforms designer nature) and it becomes very difficult to manage; However to the user there is no problem as controls are shown on demand.

So how could i hide some controls at the designer so it's more easy to manage ?

Comment: heck, so how could the big programs do there design. it became a hell hard for me with only some controls how would it be with hundreds of them

Comment: you can put the controls on different panles and do BringToFront or SendToBack


http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/is/csharpide/thread/9c3ae9d1-432e-49e8-a389-91f6279a2312

Comment: But if i send a panel pack how could i select it again (due to it is being behind another panel ...) am i supposed to resize it to the what is behind and that hell ?

Comment: TabControl has nice design time support, hide the tabs like this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2798241/17034