# Hiding Items in designer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Is there a way to hide items in the designer view? for example, I have 2 radio buttons, that when selected show different textboxes etc... but I cannot add the other items into my form without them interfering with the current items already in place.

I have a comboBox placed down, but want to place labels in that same place when a specific radio button is selected, I have the coding down, so when my app launches it knows to automatically hide said ComboBox unless radio button is selected - I want to hide it in the designer form.

[image]

The image shows the combobox that I want to hide.

**I'm using Winforms / C#**
**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Hide Controls At Design-Time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13122371/hide-controls-at-design-time), [Winforms - how to show/hide elements in designer?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9998672/8967612)

Comment: You move them backwards so you don't select them when you click on them

Answer (score -1):

Try using the `.Visible = false;` attribute after whatever code you have implemented. Example:

```
label1.Visible = false;
```

Comment: Doesn't change the visibility in the Designer. -- Maybe a custom CodeDomSerializer? Or custom Controls that paint themselves as *transparent* (or don't render at all based on conditions)? Who knows.