# Designing a custom TabPage, was this approach acceptable?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, tabcontrol, tabpage

I have a situation where I am loading many tab pages, but the tab pages need to have a collection of controls on them when they're loaded.

The way I worked around this was to create a new control - CustomTab : UserControl.
This gave me access to the designer, but in order to configure a tab I still had to drag out a TabControl. So with the tab control out, I configure a single tab with all the controls I need (along with a lot of user control and database logic). Then I include a method that returns the TabPage control.

So in my main application, I have a normal TabControl set up on the form. Anytime I need a new tab, in the code I first make an instance of my CustomTab, then add the tab to the forms TabControl via my CustomTabs return method.

How bad of a  design is this? It seems a little strange having an entire TabControl to just host the tab even though the control is never used, but it just makes designing new tabs such a breeze (have a template user control set up I just copy and start designing the tab).

Am I wasting any significant amount of resources? And is there a more efficient way this could be done that would still allow me to design the tabs?

Best Regards,
John W.

Comment: It is very unclear why you need the TabControl at all.  A UserControl already opens in its own designer.  Just create multiple user controls, you're not stuck with just CustomTab.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hide TabControl buttons to manage stacked Panel controls](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798215/hide-tabcontrol-buttons-to-manage-stacked-panel-controls)

Comment: Hans, the problem was I couldn't figure out how to "design" the tab using the designer. There's no option to just drag a TabPage out and drop it on the designer, that's what the TabControl was for, a host so that I could make a tab.