# Panels in same area in winform

Tags: c#, winforms

I currently have a windows form that I am  using as a "holder" for many panels. All of these panels are being used like pages, so say I have a default panel, a details panel etc. They all cover the exact same area and i am using a top menu to have buttons to show/hide the correct panel.

The problem I have with this is that I cannot select one panel and edit it or simply bring it to the front to edit it in "design" mode, I currently have to keep sending the top panel to the back until I get the one I need. This is okay now, but eventually my program will have over 20 panel type pages, and this will get tedious.

Is there a better way to manage this, or is there an easier way than using panels?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ungroup panels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19054809/ungroup-panels)

Answer (score 4):

**All these panels are used like pages**
Above line in your question suggests that you should be using `TabPage` instead of Panels.
Therefore, You can use a `TabControl`, and add `TabPage` to it both at design time as well as at runtime easily, and add controls of your choice to  the different `TabPage`(s).
According to wikipedia:-
**Tab is one that allows multiple documents to be contained within a single window, using tabs as a navigational widget for switching between sets of documents.  which is essentially what you want to do.**
As shown in the picture

[image]

You can then use `Button` to switch b/w different `TabPage` or show/hide `TabPage`.
It will not only solve your problem of designing at design time, it will also provide a "clean" user interface. Hope that helps!

Check this:- 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tab_(GUI)

Answer (score 3):

Use a [`TabControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead. It will allow you to switch an active panel also in design time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the panel method there is a way of working around the problem of one panel becoming an element of another. Drag the panel outside the boundary of the other panel (so that it is no longer an element of the other panel) and then **re-position it using the arrow keys** on your keyboard (i.e. *not* by dragging it into position over the other panel using the mouse). It seems like the panel will only become an element of another panel if it is dragged into position over the top of another panel using the mouse.