# Switch between panels

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, panel

I have 3 panels in 1 form to go through a process to input certain data. When the next button in a panel is clicked the next panel should be displayed.
Initially I have enabled the visibility of first panel and disabled the visibility of other panels. 
When the next button is clicked the below code will be executed.

```
      panel1.Visible = false;
      panel2.Visible = true;
```

For the purpose of development I have put them side by side(not one upon another) and it woks perfect.
But when I put them one upon another the above code does not appear to be wok, which means when the next button is clicked it just shows a empty form.
Then I added below code too.

```
    panel1.SendToBack();
    panel2.BringToFront();
```

But it didn't work. Can someone help me with this.
Thank you.

Answer (score 10):

This always goes wrong in the designer, the bottom panel will become the Parent of the top one.  So if you hide the bottom one you can never see see the top one.

This can be worked around with View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline, drag the top panel back to the form.  Still pretty painful, you typically have to edit the Location by hand and making any changes to the form in the designer later tends to slurp the panel back.

There are better ways to do this.  Creating UserControls instead is highly recommended, they have their own design surface.  Or use the RAD way and do this with a TabControl instead.  All you have to do is hide the tabs at runtime, the subject of [this Q+A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2798215/hide-tabcontrol-buttons-to-manage-stacked-panel-controls).

Comment: Now, in VS 2017, There are up and down arrows in the tool bar of the Document Outline which changes the top panel. (the Z-order I presume). I was going nearly nuts trying to figure this out and I still can't see where this info is stored. Now I can change my panels without docking and undocking and usually get one panel as a child of another. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You have to be careful when putting container controls like a  `Panel` 'one upon another '.

In the designer you **can** do it, but **only** by carfully moving the panel with the **keyboard**. Using the mouse will always put the moved one **into** not **upon** the other one whenever its top left corner gets inside the other one.

As an alternative you can do the moving in code.

Doing it in code has the advantage of still being able to work with the lower panels and its content. Sometimes I stuff them into the tabpages of an (at runtime invisible) dummy tab and move it in or out of the pages to hide and show them..

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code you can use to have multiple panels at the same time and switch between them with the next buttom added to the form.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel3.Visible = false;
        panel2.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (panel1.Visible)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = true;
            panel3.Visible = false;
        }
        else if (panel2.Visible)
        {
            panel1.Visible = false;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = true;
        }
        else if (panel3.Visible)
        {
            panel1.Visible = true;
            panel2.Visible = false;
            panel3.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Of course if you **tagged** your panels in ascending/descending format no gap between the tags for example 1,2,3,4 or 5,4,3,2 not 1,2,4 you could use this code

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        panel1.Visible = true;
        panel2.Visible = false;
        panel3.Visible = false;
    }

    private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TogglePanels();
    }
    public void TogglePanels()
    {
        List<Panel> allPanelsInForm = new List<Panel>();
        foreach (var control in Controls)
        {
            if (control is Panel)
                allPanelsInForm.Add(control as Panel);
        }
        Panel visiblePanel = allPanelsInForm.Where(o => o.Visible).FirstOrDefault();
        int nextPanelId = Convert.ToInt32(visiblePanel.Tag) + 1;
        bool nextPanelExists = allPanelsInForm.Exists(o => Convert.ToInt32(o.Tag) == nextPanelId);
        nextPanelId = nextPanelExists ? nextPanelId : 1;
        foreach (Panel panel in allPanelsInForm)
        {
            panel.Visible = Convert.ToInt32(panel.Tag) == nextPanelId ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

I wish it could help you.

Comment: I am sorry but this is what I have in my code too. This doesn't work as it should be.

Comment: ok bro but just for your assurance I myself check this code with VS2013 and all of them works like a charm. Can you try this code with an empty project? maybe that is kind of help