# Multiple Panels in C#

Tags: c#, panels

I'm creating a program where there is one form and there are 6 panels.
I just want to show the 6 panels in one form.
It's like They are top of each other.

When I click the first button, the first panel will show.
when I click the second button, the second panel will show and the first panel will hide.
so on and so forth.

I use the

```
panel1.Visible = true/False; Method.
```

but when i Clicked the second button, the panel2 are not shown in the form.
thank you in advance!

Comment: Show us some code so we can help you solve your problem.

Comment: This smells [very familiar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35741177/hide-show-windows-forms-panel-in-c-sharp).

Comment: Use View > (Other Windows) > Document Outline.  And you can now see that panel2 is *inside* panel1.  So if you hide panel1 then panel2 can never be visible.  Fix it by dragging the panel to the form and (carefully) editing its Location property.  There are [better ways to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2798241/17034).

Comment: Adding to Hans' adivice to edit the __location__ values: You can also use the __keyboard__ to place the controls on top of each other. Just __don't use the mouse__, as it will always try to __nest controls inside__ others, whenever these are containers like panels.. And of course there are nice __tool buttons__ in the layout toolstrip to __align__ them top and left and make their size the same, all without any nesting! And sometimes I use [this trick](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31498890/switch-between-panels/31501261?s=2|0.1183#31501261) to make work in the designer easier..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
panel1.BringToFront();
```

this will get the panel1 on top of all the other panels.

Answer (score 0):

have a activePanel variable which refers to the panel that is active.
whenever a button is clicked make the activePanel.visible= false.

then set appropriate panel to activePanel.