# Turning off a TabControl/TabPage visual display

Tags: vb.net, winforms

We have a number of apps spun from common code, differing primarily in some settings which turn on/off a number of features. Normally each feature is controlled by a number of controls displayed in a TabPage in a TabControl, so depending on the app settings, there might be one or more tabs of controls.

Now in the case where there is only one tab, which is quite common, you end up with a bunch of controls inside a tab which is superfluous. Is there some *easy* way to turn off the tab control's visuals so it looks like it's controls are on the underlying form instead?

Comment: You may find [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2798241/3110834) helpful.

Comment: I did indeed! If you make that an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Just upvote the original and perhaps close this as a dupe

Comment: Thank you for your kind feedback:) You can consider an upvote for @HansPassant [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2798241/3110834). All credit goes to him :)