# Add object's code in another Class Library Project with Reference - Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio

I have a Windows Form Project called Odest Installer. It is a custom Installer with custom features. It consists of 4 forms. What I want to do is I want some Objects (Eg. Textbox) to have their Source Code Located in a Class Library Project called Multiple Installs Extension. I've tried this:

In Multiple Installs Extension (Class Library Project):

```
Imports Odest_Installer

Dim getval As Integer
Public Class Class1
   Public Sub txtboxshow ()

      If TextBox1.Value < 3 Then
         Button4.Disabled = True
         TextBox1.Text = "3"
      Else
      EndIf
      If TextBox1.Value = 3 Then
         Button4.Disabled = True
      Else
      EndIf
      If TextBox1.Value > 1 Then
         Button5.Disabled = True
         TextBox1.Text = "1"
      Else
      EndIf
      If TextBox1.Value = 1 Then
         Button5.Disabled = True
      Else
      EndIf
   End Sub
   Public Sub btn4()
      getval = TextBox1.Value + 1
   End Sub
   Public Sub btn5()
      getval = TextBox1.Value - 1
   End Sub
End Class
```

In Odest Installer (WindowsFormApplication):

```
Imports ClassLibrary1
Public Class Form 3
   Private Sub TextBox1.TextChanged() Handles TextBox1.TextChanged
      txtboxshow()
   End Sub  
   Private Sub Button4.OnClick() Handles Button1.Onclick
      btn4()
   End Sub
   Private Sub Button5.OnClick() Handles Button1.Onclick
      btn5()
   End Sub
End Class
```

The TextBox1 gets an error "Textbox1 is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level" even after giving a Reference to each Other. Am I going wrong somewhere or You have another way of Referencing these two Projects. (Note: I don't want to Add Multiple Installs Extensions into my Project so it can become portable)

Comment: What do you mean? I'm totally new to Referencing Two Projects.

Comment: See the Edits (In the code). This may Help you

Comment: If you know another way of Referencing two projects from which one depends on the others' code then please write it as an answer below.

Comment: See, There is a Button (For an Example). It's code is located in a different file just like index.html's design is located in main.css. If the source file isn't there, the Button won't appear in my Main form (`Form1`) and if it is, and when the user clicks on the button it'll read the code from that file and perform the actions as directed.

Comment: Want picture explanation?

Comment: Okay then, see another edit. It may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of problems with your code - TextBoxes don't have `.value` properties so you'll need to convert the `.text` property to and integer each time.

To be honest - unless there is a reason why the code in the class library needs to be separate, you should keep it all within your form's class definition.

However - if you need the code in a separate class, try this

Rather than try to reference the form directly in your class library, change your class library definitions so that they accept the controls and getval as parameters, and change the code to match.

Like this

```
Public Sub txtboxshow(tBox1 As TextBox, btn4 As Button, btn5 As Button)

    If CInt(tBox1.Text) < 3 Then
        btn4.Enabled = False
        tBox1.Text = "3"
    Else
    End If
    If CInt(tBox1.Text) = 3 Then
        btn4.Enabled = False
    Else
    End If
    If CInt(tBox1.Text) > 1 Then
        btn5.Enabled = False
        tBox1.Text = "1"
    Else
    End If
    If CInt(tBox1.Text) = 1 Then
        btn5.Enabled = False
    Else
    End If
End Sub
Public Sub btn4(tbox1 As TextBox, ByRef getval As Integer)
    getval = CInt(tbox1.Text) + 1
End Sub
Public Sub btn5(tbox1 As TextBox, ByRef getval As Integer)
    getval = CInt(tbox1.Text) - 1
End Sub
```

There are however possible logic problems with the `if.. End If` statements in `txtBoxShow`.

If `.text="3"`

The first `If` statement will leave it alone and leave button4 in it's original state.

The second `If` statement will leave `textbox1` alone and disable `button4`

The third `If` statement will set `textbox1.text` to "1" and disable `button5`

Because textbox1 now contains "1, the fourth `If` will also disable `button5`

So if `textbox1` contains three, you will end up with `button4` and `button5` disabled and `textbox1` will contain "1"

It doesn't seem like this is behaviour you want. Your `If` statements may need rewriting.